# Mutliple applications doing a poll on a descriptor

Tags: file-io, linux-kernel

Can multiple processes(not threads) poll on a device descriptor (For ex: /dev/xyx) in blocking mode and get woken up when the driver does a return POLLIN ?

Details: I have a driver and to support async event notification from the driver to user space apps, I have implemented a poll functionality in the driver. I am expecting multiple processes to do poll on my descriptor /dev/xyz, on doing poll, immediately driver puts them on a wait queue from the .poll function, so that they block until the driver returns a POLLIN.

Now, it works fine when one process is blocked on the descriptor, so when the driver does a POLLIN, the poll() unblocks and I process it. However if there are multiple processes blocked on the /dev/xyz (by doing poll) and if the driver sends a POLLIN, only one of the processes is unblocking and the other is still blocked.

Is there a way to make sure that all processes blocked on that descriptor is woken up when the driver does a POLLIN on the /dev/xyz ? (Like walking through the wait queue list or something ) ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to replace wake_up (or wake_up_interruptible) with wake_up_all (wake_up_interruptible_all). This should awake all waiting processes.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I tried wake_up_interruptible_all() but still i see that only one of the two processes, which are blocked is getting unblocked. My second process is clueless about the event and it stays blocked on the poll sys call. I am doing poll(fd, 1 , -1) in my processes. I have verified from the driver that both the process are put on the wait queue(using printks).    Any more suggestions are more than welcome. Thanks

Comment: I can just throw some "maybe"s. Maybe the two processes weren't on the same wait queue. Maybe after wake up, Linux called the poll handler for it again, and it was put to sleep again. Maybe you have a race condition between putting on the wait queue and checking if there's data (but this would explain consistent behavior).